# How to handle http errors in Simple HTML Dom Parser

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

so I have this,

```
$r1pro = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/forums-profile.php?user_id='.$uid);
$uname = $r1pro->find('span.username', 0);
```

It works perfectly, but the site isn't very welly designed and if you're not logged in, some requests return a 500 error, which outputs something like this:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.example.com/forums-profile.php?user_id=12345678): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error in /home/mysite/public_html/su3/htmldom.php on line 76
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in /home/mysite/public_html/su3/index.php on line 61
```

I've searched for methods for error handling in simplehtmldom but have found nothing. Is there any way to catch an http error and run some different code instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I feel really stupid now. All I had to do was

```
if($r1pro){
<--do normal stuff if no error-->
}else{
<--do stuff in case of error-->
}
```